# Left align text above and below inline elements within a parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to left align (dynamically generated) text above and below some inline (side by side) images. The leftmost image should also be left aligned.

```css
.inline-attachments {
    display:inline; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">text top left above inline images

<div class="inline-attachments"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2duxRXndQoYlHxjCw2U6rQTOJPYvFqx6AzA&usqp=CAU" /></div>
                    
<div class="inline-attachments"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2duxRXndQoYlHxjCw2U6rQTOJPYvFqx6AzA&usqp=CAU" /></div>
                    
text bottom left below inline images</div>
```

Simply placing paragraph tags around the inline div would work, but it's not an option.

Could anyone advise how to achieve it with css?

**Edit to thank Bert W for the solution (see his 3rd comment) using JS to work with arbitrary number of images and image sizes.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a final edit to my solution that worked for the person asking the question. I have a link to this solution in codepen in the comments below but I wanted to update for anyone looking at this post in the future.

```js
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.inline-attachments');
for (let i=0; i < img.length; i++){
  let parent = document.querySelector('.content');
  if (img[i]===img[0]){
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    parent.insertBefore(p, img[i]);
  } else if (img[i]===parent.lastElementChild){
      let p = document.createElement('p');
      img[i].appendChild(p); 
  }
}
```

```css
.inline-attachments {
    display:inline; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">text top left above inline images
<div class="inline-attachments"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2duxRXndQoYlHxjCw2U6rQTOJPYvFqx6AzA&usqp=CAU" /></div>
                    
<div class="inline-attachments"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2duxRXndQoYlHxjCw2U6rQTOJPYvFqx6AzA&usqp=CAU" /></div>   
<div class="inline-attachments"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2duxRXndQoYlHxjCw2U6rQTOJPYvFqx6AzA&usqp=CAU" /></div> 
text bottom left below inline images</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, because the text is dynamically inserted by BBCode, I can't insert tags into the html. I'm looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: Sorry - it now dawns on me that this won't work for this purpose, as the images are also dynamically generated. Their size and the number of them inside the content div will vary. Use of position absolute is also going to cause overlaps and misalignment with other elements in the page. I wonder if there is some way to remove the latter part of the text from its inline style.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to use JavaScript. I was able to work something out where I can add multiple images and I don't believe height or width of the image will matter. You will have to create a JS file and add that to your project, not sure if that's possible. Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/gOLKjgr

Comment: That is brilliant. Thank you so much.